# Reduce the vibration

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am using a vibrator to vibrate every time you click on any key on the layout, but camera shake is too strong, no way to vibrator gently as clicking on the virtual keyboard on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to vibrate more gentle - decrease vibration time to 25-40 milliseconds. Vibrator it self doesn't have "vibration power" option.